# Replacing a comma with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I encountered a problem with quite simple thing I guess, I want to replace each comma ',' in a string except for the ones that are surrounded by digits.
Examples:

```
hey, world -> hey,\nworld
hey  ,  world -> hey,\nworld
they are simple, but now also:
hey,world -> hey,\nworld
hey),world -> hey),\nworld
(1,2) -> (1,2) << no change :P
```

I tried it with different Regexes and I can't really get it working as easily as I'd like to. Matching the commas that I need is quite easy but the problem is that I thought I can do it this way:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]\s*,\s*[^\d]", ",\n");
```

it works cool but it changes my:

```
hey,world into: he,\norld
```

I'd be glad if you could help me figure that out :)

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: The space removal of row 2 is wanted?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to remove all the spaces as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This uses negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` and negative lookahead `(?!...)` to check for the presence of digits.

```
(?<![0-9])\s*,\s*|\s*,\s*(?![0-9])
```

It means: not preceded by digits OR not followed by digits. So the only failure case is: preceded by digits AND followed by digits.

Be aware that `\d` is different than `[0-9]`. `ԱԲԳԴԵԶԷԸԹ0123456789` are `\d` (and many others) (they are [Armenian numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_numerals)), while `0123456789` are `[0-9]`

My original regex was TOTALLY WRONG! Because it was: not-preceded by digits AND not-followed by digits, while the request was: non-preceded by digits OR not followed by digits.

Comment: Ahh, that was exactly what I was looking for, I heard about these lookbehinds/aheads but I didn't know what it does in fact, now its clear :]  thank you ;)

Comment: @AndrzejCzerwoniec Just one clarification: the negative lookahead is **not** `(?!=...)`, but `(?!...)`. I fixed the regex in an edit.

Comment: Alright ;) the one with equals sign worked for me as well though :P

Comment: @AndrzejCzerwoniec The one with the `=` wouldn't have replaced the `,` in `(1,a)` and `(a,=1)`

Comment: I see, but I found out that id doesn't match it now either ;P
It can't find any digit before and after to match, so it still won't match the (1,a), or have I dont somthing wrong?:p

Comment: @AndrzejCzerwoniec Changed totally

Answer (score 1):

You need to use lookaheads to only match the comma, not the characters before and after the comma:

```
(?=[^\d]\s*),(?=\s*[^\d])
```

Adding the removal of spaces shown in the second example:

```
(?=[^\d]\s*)[ ]*,[ ]*(?=\s*[^\d])
```

Comment: I wanted to get rid of all whitespaces, so the first one is cool, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your match contains the characters you don't want to replace, you should use the *negative lookahead assertion* and the *negative lookbehind assertion*.
[Here's a good site for regex.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

```
@"(?<!\d)\s*,\s*(?!\d)"
```

The above regex will replace the comma and any spaces directly before or after it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that site, I'll surely take a closer look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace with an empty string.

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?![0-9])\s*,\s*(?![0-9])", "");
```

Comment: I think you didn't quite understand the question: OP wants to replace `a,b` or `a, b` or `a   ,   b` (any number of spaces directly before or after comma) to `a,\nb`; but **not** `1,2` or `1, 2`, etc. Your `Regex.Replace` replaces both.

Comment: Read the question again: `(1,2) -> (1,2) << no change :P` means that the comma is **not** supposed to be replaced, when it separates two **numbers**.

Comment: what happen ? if start with <?!..>

Comment: If your regex is `a(?!b)` and you use `Regex.Replace` to replace `abc` with `0`, you will get `abc`, because the regex didn't match. If you want to replace `aac` with `0`, you will get `00c`, because the regex did match, but the match only contains a single `a` at a time; similarly `aaac` will be `000c`. If your regex is instead `a[^b]` then `abc` will remain `abc`, but `aac` will be replaced to `0c` because the match contains `aa`, so `aaac` will become `00`. Also, `(?!...)` is *lookahead*, so `a(?!b)` and `(?!b)a` do the same. *Lookbehind* is `(?<!...)`